# Morphia @PrePersist in @Embedded objects

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have the following Item and Video classes:

```
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;    
@Entity(value = "item")
public class Item{
    @Id
    ObjectId id;
    Date modified;
    String title;
    Video video;
    @PrePersist 
    void preItem() {
        modified = new Date();
    }
}
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Embedded;    
@Embedded
public class Video{
    Date modified;
    @PrePersist 
    void preVideo() {
        modified = new Date();
    }
}
```

Anytime I save the item object, the date is modified in the Item and in the Video classes. That's the expected result when calling: `datastore.save(this)`.

There is a non-manual way to update the date whenever the object really changes and not whenever a save is performed?

Comparing the new object (in memory) with the old one (in the database) could be a solution:

```
//Inside the Item class
@PrePersist
void preItem(){
    Item oldItem=find.query().field("_id").equal(this.id)
        .field("video").equal(this.video).get()
    if(oldItem != null) oldItem.video.modified;         
}
```

But that means that in every call to `datastore.save(this)` I will query the db. Is it not recommended, from a performance point of view? There are other better ways to do it?

**EDIT:**
The goal is to have a real modified date value. Let's imagine I modify the title of the item: `item.title="Whatever"`. Then I perform `item.save()`. This will update my date in item.modified and in item.video.modified. But this is actually wrong: the item has been modified, but not the video.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

It won't work that way. `prePersist()` will always run on the full document when you call `save`. You'll need to issue an update query or set it explicitly.

AFAIK MongoDB doesn't check for changes, so this won't work without some manual intervention

---

Old answer:

Mixing the datastore into entities looks weird to me — I'd try to avoid that. And you are right, the performance would suffer and you might (generally) run into concurrency issues since there are no transactions.

Wouldn't the following work?

```
@PrePersist 
void preItem() {
    modified = new Date();
    video.setModified(new Date()); // or probably fetch new Date() once and use it for both
}
```

PS: Since you already have the date in the document, why do you need to save it into the embedded subdocument as well? The two should always match, shouldn't they?

Comment: No. Maybe I was not clear with my question: I want that the video.modified only has a new date when the video object is really modified. To save an Item object, does not imply that the video object embed inside item was modified. Maybe the item object has more fields and I modify them BUT I do not modify anything inside the video object.

Comment: Thanks. Is what I thought. I guess the best idea in terms of performance is to update the modified field in every object, every time I am aware I am really modified that object. Thanks for your opinion anyway